# Problem launching a MapActivity

Tags: android

My app force closes when I try to launch the same MapActivity from the HelloGoogleMaps tutorial. I am launching it from my main activity which is just a list:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, HelloGoogleMaps.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

HelloGoogleMaps works fine by itself and the class is in my manifest. I tried tracing the problem with the debugger and it crashes somewhere when create my Intent. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this method a part of a subclass of your Activity?  Can you show more of the Activity that this method belongs in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, figured it out. I was pulling my hair out for a long time and then figure it out moments after I post this question.

I forgot to put

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in my manifest.